# Why is post sharp asking for a serial key when I am not using its paid feature?

Tags: aop, postsharp

I am using PostSharp OnExceptionAspect in one my projects. I believe this is available in the express version and I should be able to use it without a key. However when I build my project PS gives me an error and says my project is using a feature that is in the Basic version and I need to obtain the license. When I double click on error it does not take me to the code usage.

What have I missed and how can I find out which feature I am using that is causing this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PostSharp OnExceptionAspect with the Express edition, but the Express edition also requires a license key. You only have to request the key for free on the purchase page here http://www.postsharp.net/purchase.